# Routing a url to fetch content from another site

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, rewrite, arr

Environment: IIS 7.

I have a default site `www.domain.com` and its folder is `C:Inetpub/wwwroot/domain` There is subdomain `www.subdomain.domain.com` and its folder is `C:Inetpub/wwwroot/domain/subdomain`.

Now I have setup a new website at an external server. I cannot put the content on the above server due to some reasons.

I need the URL `www.subdomain.domain.com/blog` fetch content from this external server while the URL should remain the same.

How could this be achieved in IIS 7?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method maybe to use an iframe. Otherwise you could have the /blog page make a webrequest to the other server, and return that to the user; basically acting as a proxy.